# TFS vNext build Test Impact Analysis- Impacted unit tests are not running at all

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines, vnext, vstest.console.exe

I have a VB Solution having 1 project and corresponding unit test project in it.

TIA is enabled. But during code check-in, impacted unit tests are not getting executed.

If I add any new method and then write the corresponding unit test, then TIA is running newly added unit test only as part of impacted unit test.

Any clue, why my impacted unit tests are not getting triggered.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: My project file has methods which are used for database call to get some data information and showing it in win form.  Unit tests are written for the same.

Comment: Whenever I am changing anything in test project then it is picking and running that unit test only. but not for the actual code change.